# Best way to trim spaces, CRs, LFs in a CSV field during LOAD DATA INFILE in PHP/MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, trim, load-data-infile, data-cleaning

There are about 4500 questions asked about LOAD DATA INFILE, but none I could find that addressed my specific issue.

I have users uploading CSV files into a MySQL database (I'm using the LOAD DATA INFILE script on the backend), and sometimes the fields have goofy characters that need to be cleaned out ...specifically spaces, CRs and LFs.

Here's the LOAD query:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '".$csvfile."' INTO TABLE table_name FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '\"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n' IGNORE 1 LINES
(@dummy,Field2,Field3,Field4)
SET Field1 = (SELECT ID FROM table_a WHERE Username = 'foo');
```

The code works just fine, all I want to do is cleanup incoming fields that might have junk characters. I believe I can simply do the cleanup in the SET line by using REPLACE ...Is this true?

```
SET Field1 = (SELECT ID FROM table_a WHERE Username = 'foo'), REPLACE(Field2,'\r\n','');
```

Another idea I had was to handle this in a subsequent query:

```
$trimQuery = "UPDATE table_name SET Field2 = TRIM(Field2), Field2 = REPLACE(Field2,'\r\n','')";
```

So my question is four-fold:

1. Will it break the input if there ARE NOT any junk characters to find?

   What if I want to trim spaces also?

   What if there is only '\r', will it get skipped or fail?

   Is there a better way using regex somehow?

Thanks!!

Comment: How about just loading up the dumpfile as is, then doing an update query with trim/replace on each field which needs the treatment?

Comment: @Marc I just updated my initial question with that alternative. Does it look right?